# Configuring PhpRedis in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, redis, phpredis, laravel-facade

I've set up a fresh installation of Laravel in Homestead and I've installed PhpRedis as recommended in the Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redis#phpredis.

I followed this guide for installing PhpRedis https://webstoked.com/install-phpredis-laravel-ubuntu/

In both the Laravel docs, and the guide I've linked for installing PhpRedis, I'm instructed to rename the Redis alias in config/app.php.

> If you plan to use PhpRedis extension along with the Redis Facade alias, you should rename it to something else, like RedisManager, to avoid a collision with the Redis class. You can do that in the aliases section of your app.php config file.
>   - *Laravel Docs*

To further add to my confusion, the Laravel docs then go on to say that you should remove the alias entirely.

> To avoid class naming collisions with the Redis PHP extension itself, you will need to delete or rename the Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis facade alias from your app configuration file's aliases array. Generally, you should remove this alias entirely and only reference the facade by its fully qualified class name while using the Redis PHP extension.
>   - *Laravel Docs*

My main questions are:

1. What does, "If you plan to use PhpRedis extension along with the Redis Facade alias", mean?
2. When should I rename the alias, remove it, or leave it as-is?
3. Depending on if I rename or remove the alias, how will this affect using Redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different configurations/ways to use `redis` in a laravel project.

1. First one is to use `predis` and it is in your `vendor` folder. This one is "Flexible and feature-complete Redis client for PHP and HHVM" located [here](https://github.com/nrk/predis). It is a package/library written in `php`.
2. The other way to do is using `PhpRedis`, it is an extension written in `C` and located [here](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis).

```
protected function connector()
{
    switch ($this->driver) {
        case 'predis':
            return new Connectors\PredisConnector;
        case 'phpredis':
            return new Connectors\PhpRedisConnector;
    }
}
```

---

1. What does, "If you plan to use PhpRedis extension along with the Redis Facade alias", mean?

   > In the framework there is a [check](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php#L71-L75). While creating the `PhpRedis client` of Redis, it is checking whether the `new Redis` instance is Facade because PhpRedis is also using `Redis` name is you can see from [here](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#example). So if you want to use PhpRedis in your laravel framework you better rename your facade because it will cause collision.
2. When should I rename the alias, remove it, or leave it as-is?

   > If you are going to use `predis` as client, then you can leave it as-is. If you are going to use `PhpRedis` as client, then you need to rename alias.
3. Depending on if I rename or remove the alias, how will this affect using Redis?

   > You will use `RedisManager::someMethod()` if you choose PhpRedis. You will use `Redis::someMethod()` if you use predis.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm still very confused though =/

I renamed my alias to RedisManager in my config/app.php file.
I then tried to use it in my controller with 
```
$visits = RedisManager::incr('visits');
return $visits;
```
But I get: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\RedisManager' not found.

I tried adding use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RedisManager; as well, but I get the same error.

Comment: Not that I'm any more enlightened, but I found that I couldn't use 'use Redis', but instead had to use 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;'. So I did the reverse and changed 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RedisManager;' to just 'use RedisManager' and it seems to be working.

Comment: @Josh it depends on your `client` choice - Actually it doesn't change the facade - facade will be same but alias will be different. I think you made it work by `use RedisManager`.